# Bootstrap Datepicker re-initialize date format

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have Bootstrap datepicker with default format **mm/dd/yyyy**, and I have select where I can change
format **from mm/dd/yyyy** to **dd/mm/yyyy** and reverse.

On select change I want to my datepicker change format.

I tried

```
find('#options-date_format').on('change', function(){
    $("#picker").datepicker({format: formatDate})
});
```

but It's not working, and I can't find way of doing this.
Also tried to remove / destroy datepicker but I got javascript error.

Comment: didn't try it but sounds logical: destroy and reinitialize.

Comment: Can you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Seems I'm using old version, so I don't have remove function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I resolve this extending bootstra-datepicker.js

```
setFormat: function(format) {
    this.format = DPGlobal.parseFormat(format);
}
```

And call that function

```
find('#options-date_format').on('change', function(){
    $("#picker").datepicker('setFormat', newFormat);
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain this answer better?
I am in an eternal argument with all datepickers & cannot get any of them to do format update.

Answer (score 16):

I think the below approach is working,

1, Whenever changing the format, de-attach and then re-attach back to the element.

```
$("#dp3").datepicker();  // initialization
$('select').on('change', function () {
    var d = $('select option:selected').text();
    if (d == 2) {
        $("#dp3").datepicker('remove'); //detach
        $("#dp3").datepicker({          //re attach
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
        })
    } else {
        $("#dp3").datepicker('remove'); //detach
        $("#dp3").datepicker({          //re attach
            format: "mm/dd/yyyy"
        })
    }
});
```

### [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/YY5rh/1/)

Answer (score 2):

When you have many date pickers, the you can use a class selector and reset all of them, and initialize using the class. Code sample below.
In the example, all the input elements will have the class `date-picker`

```
function resetDatePickers(){
    $('.date-picker').each(function(index){
       $(this).datepicker('remove');
    });

    $('.date-picker').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        startView: 2,
        orientation: "top auto"
    });
}


resetDatePickers();
```