# How can I reinitialize a bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

A bootstrap datepicker is initialized on load. How can I change the options for that datepicker *after* the page is loaded and the datepicker has already been initialized?

See here for an example http://jsfiddle.net/Leoqs1xg/

The weekStart is set to 4 (Thursday) at first with

```
$('#mydate').datepicker({weekStart: 4});
```

but if I change it to something else with

```
$('#mydate').datepicker({weekStart: 1});
```

weekStart is still 4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Datepicker re-initialize date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479100/bootstrap-datepicker-re-initialize-date-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to remove and re-initialize the object

More info here

[Bootstrap Datepicker re-initialize date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479100/bootstrap-datepicker-re-initialize-date-format)

Answer (score 15):

There is  now a method `destroy` available.

I would do it like this:

```
$('#sv_pickup_date').datepicker('destroy').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    , autoclose: true
    , startDate: '20/08/2018'
    , endDate: '24/08/2018'
});
```

Optionally you may want to also use `clearDates` method.

Like this you can define your own `reinitialize` method for bootstap datepicker.

Comment: Working fine for me

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same hurdle in my current project where on change of dropdown I recreate and recheck the available dates. So for that purpose I needed to send over ajax new enabled dates. @strapro was on the right track.

```
if (called_from_type_of_retreat == 'IGR') {
    var myMinDateToday = getTodaysDate();
    var enabledDatesArrayIGR = '';
    $('#arrival_date_div_IGR').datetimepicker();
    /*Ajax call for IGR*/
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "getAjaxAvailableDatesIGR",
        data: {
        "todays_date": myMinDateToday
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            /*Assign array which is returned as Json*/
            enabledDatesArrayIGR = data.availableDatesArray;
            /* DateTime Pickers */
            $('#arrival_date_div_IGR').datetimepicker('destroy');
            $('#arrival_date_div_IGR').datetimepicker({
                format: "DD.MM.YYYY",
                ignoreReadonly: true,
                enabledDates: enabledDatesArrayIGR
            });
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Pay attention to raw initialize of datetimepicker lines 4.

Then in Ajax call I destroy that datetimepicker (line 17) of datetimepicker and set my settings line (18-22).

My version of [eonasdan bootstrap datetimepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) is : 4.17.45

Comment: datetimepicker('destroy') , works for me, to reinitialize the datetimepicker....thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no re-initialization. However if you update the value of the input programmatically, for example another part of your code, and want to see the change when you open the picker you could use setDate to read the new value.

```
// var mynewdate = your-converted-to-date-string;
$('.datepicker').datepicker('setDate', mynewdate);
```