# Change bootstrap date picker views dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I need to change the view of the date picker dynamically. Have few buttons(month, year, day). I am trying to achieve the below:

1. On selecting particular button say **month**

> I want date picker to render the months only.

2. On selecting **year**

> I want date picker to render the years only.

Below is the code and [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/qazovepucu/edit?html,js,output) link

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap- 
 datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap- 
datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="startdate">
    <br><br>
    <button class="btn" value="year">year</button>
    <button class="btn" value="month">Month</button>
    <button class="btn" value="day">Day</button>
    <script>
       var viewType = "day";    
         $(document).ready(function(){
        });

        const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
        btns.forEach(function(elem){
            elem.addEventListener("click", function(e){
                viewType = e.target.value;
            });
        });
        $('#startdate').click(function(){   
            CheckCalendarView();
        });

        function CheckCalendarView(){
                if(viewType === "month"){
                        $('#startdate').datepicker({
                            format: 'MM/yyyy',
                            startView: "months",
                            minViewMode: "months",
                        });
                    }else if(viewType === "day"){
                        $('#startdate').datepicker({
                            format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
                            todayHighlight: true,
                            startView: "days",
                            minViewMode: "days",
                            startDate: new Date(),
                        });
                    }else{
                        $('#startdate').datepicker({
                            format: "yyyy",
                            startView: "years",
                            minViewMode: "years",
                        });
                    }   
            }

        
    </script>
</body>
```

**I am failing in the re-rendering/re-initializing the views..**

Comment: Consider updating your libraries as this version of datepicker is from 2014 and the current documentation does not always apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When changing the calendar view, you need to first call `$('#startdate').datepicker('remove')` to [reinitialize the datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21479503/378779).

You also don't need a click handler on `#startdate` since clicking it doesn't affect which calendar should show.

Your `$(document).ready()` function was wrong. It should encapsulate the JS initialization you are doing.

You were also mixing vanilla JS with jQuery to add the click handlers. I've turned them into pure jQuery.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <input id="startdate">
  <br><br>
  <button class="btn" value="year">year</button>
  <button class="btn" value="month">Month</button>
  <button class="btn" value="day">Day</button>
  <script>
    var viewType = "day";
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.btn').click(function () {
        viewType = $(this).val()
        CheckCalendarView();
      });
    });

    function CheckCalendarView() {
      $('#startdate').datepicker('remove')
      if (viewType === "month") {
        $('#startdate').datepicker({
          format: 'MM/yyyy',
          startView: "months",
          minViewMode: "months",
        });
      } else if (viewType === "day") {
        $('#startdate').datepicker({
          format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
          todayHighlight: true,
          startView: "days",
          minViewMode: "days",
          startDate: new Date(),
        });
      } else {
        $('#startdate').datepicker({
          format: "yyyy",
          startView: "years",
          minViewMode: "years",
        });
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Important:  OP is using a very old 2014 version of datepicker.  The method was renamed from "remove" to "destroy" in later versions.  And this is a problem when using the latest docs to troubleshoot an old version of datepicker because "destory" will silently fail. Anyway, nice work +1

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `date-picker` lib can not re-initialize.

I don't know whether the `bootstrap-datepicker` has the `remove()` method or not. If the answer is no, then I will use simple Javascript to hack it, like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <input id="startdate">
    <br><br>
    <button class="btn" value="year">year</button>
    <button class="btn" value="month">Month</button>
    <button class="btn" value="day">Day</button>
    <script>
      var viewType = "day";     
            $(document).ready(function(){
            const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
            btns.forEach(function(elem){
                elem.addEventListener("click", function(e){
                    viewType = e.target.value;
          
          //  use javascript to remove and create a input (id="startdate") 
          document.getElementById("startdate").remove();
          var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
          var newElement = document.createElement("input");
          newElement.setAttribute("id","startdate");
          body.insertBefore(newElement, body.firstChild);
          
          //  initialize again
          CheckCalendarView()
                });
            });

            $('#startdate').click(function(){   
                CheckCalendarView();
            });              
            });

            function CheckCalendarView(){
                    if(viewType === "month"){
                            $('#startdate').datepicker({
                                format: 'MM/yyyy',
                                startView: "months",
                                minViewMode: "months",
                            });
                        }else if(viewType === "day"){
                            $('#startdate').datepicker({
                                format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
                                todayHighlight: true,
                                startView: "days",
                                minViewMode: "days",
                                startDate: new Date(),
                            });
                        }else{
                            $('#startdate').datepicker({
                                format: "yyyy",
                                startView: "years",
                                minViewMode: "years",
                            });
                        }   
                }
    </script>
</body>
```